# Avahi out of memory error

Tags: networking, avahi

After upgrading to 16.10, avahi is consistently crashing (and successfully restarting on it's own).  It is reporting an "out of memory" error, even though there is plenty of memory on the system.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the relevant part of syslog:

```
Nov 11 10:38:33 maynardsmith avahi-daemon[8218]: Out of memory, aborting ...
Nov 11 10:38:33 maynardsmith systemd[1]: avahi-daemon.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=6/ABRT
Nov 11 10:38:33 maynardsmith systemd[1]: avahi-daemon.service: Unit entered failed state.
Nov 11 10:38:33 maynardsmith systemd[1]: avahi-daemon.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.
Nov 11 10:38:33 maynardsmith dbus[858]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.Avahi' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.Avahi.service'
Nov 11 10:38:33 maynardsmith systemd[1]: Starting Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack...
Nov 11 10:38:33 maynardsmith avahi-daemon[8553]: Process 8218 died: No such process; trying to remove PID file. (/var/run/avahi-daemon//pid)
Nov 11 10:38:33 maynardsmith avahi-daemon[8553]: Found user 'avahi' (UID 111) and group 'avahi' (GID 118).
Nov 11 10:38:33 maynardsmith avahi-daemon[8553]: Successfully dropped root privileges.
Nov 11 10:38:33 maynardsmith avahi-daemon[8553]: avahi-daemon 0.6.32 starting up.
Nov 11 10:38:33 maynardsmith dbus[858]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.Avahi'
Nov 11 10:38:33 maynardsmith systemd[1]: Started Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack.
Nov 11 10:38:33 maynardsmith avahi-daemon[8553]: Successfully called chroot().
Nov 11 10:38:33 maynardsmith avahi-daemon[8553]: Successfully dropped remaining capabilities.
Nov 11 10:38:33 maynardsmith avahi-daemon[8553]: Loading service file /services/udisks.service.
Nov 11 10:38:33 maynardsmith avahi-daemon[8553]: *** WARNING: Detected another IPv4 mDNS stack running on this host. This makes mDNS unreliable and is thus not recommended. ***
Nov 11 10:38:33 maynardsmith avahi-daemon[8553]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv6 with address fe80::cc23:b5e4:b864:6ff5.
Nov 11 10:38:33 maynardsmith avahi-daemon[8553]: New relevant interface eth0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Nov 11 10:38:33 maynardsmith avahi-daemon[8553]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv4 with address 128.2.64.41.
Nov 11 10:38:33 maynardsmith avahi-daemon[8553]: New relevant interface eth0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Nov 11 10:38:33 maynardsmith avahi-daemon[8553]: Network interface enumeration completed.
Nov 11 10:38:33 maynardsmith avahi-daemon[8553]: Registering new address record for fe80::cc23:b5e4:b864:6ff5 on eth0.*.
Nov 11 10:38:33 maynardsmith avahi-daemon[8553]: Registering new address record for 128.2.64.41 on eth0.IPv4.
Nov 11 10:38:34 maynardsmith avahi-daemon[8553]: Server startup complete. Host name is maynardsmith.local. Local service cookie is 2178163778.
```